# What does this error mean and what is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, completable-future

I have the following function:

```
  public CompletableFuture<List<String>> getUsers(final String users) {
    final CompletionStage<List<String>> cacheFuture = cache.read(users.toString());

    return cacheFuture.thenCompose((List<String> userList) -> {
      if (userList != null) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(userList);
      }
      return service.getUsers(users).thenApply((List<String> usersFresh) -> {
          cache.write(users.toString(), usersFresh);
          return usersFresh;
      });
    });
  }
```

The compiler error I am getting is:

> Bad return type in lambda expression: List cannot be converted
>   to U

on the line `return usersFresh`

The method signature for `service.getUsers` is:

`CompletableFuture<List<String>> getUsers(String users);`

I don't understand what is wrong with my code and why it won't compile.

Comment: what is `cache` in `cache.read()` and `service` in `service.getUsers()`?

Comment: One thing that I doubt is wrong here would be the `return` statement usage certainly. But would await for you to add details about the above mentioned variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `CompletionStage` to `CompletableFuture` by using `toCompletableFuture`, like:

```
  public CompletableFuture<List<String>> getUsers(final String users) {
    final CompletionStage<List<String>> cacheFuture = cache.read(users.toString());


    return cacheFuture.thenCompose((List<String> userList) -> {
      if (userList != null) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(userList);
      }
      return service.getUsers(users).thenApply((List<String> usersFresh) -> {
          cache.write(users.toString(), usersFresh);
          return usersFresh;
      });
    }).toCompletableFuture();  //!!! convert `CompletionStage` to `CompletableFuture` in here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is similar with your method want to return `ArrayList` but in method return `List`.

Let's see:

```
CompletableFuture<T> implements CompletionStage
```

Your expectation return :

```
public CompletableFuture<List<String>>
```

But `cacheFuture.thenCompose` return `CompletionStage`

You should change:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<String>> to public CompletionStage<List<String>>
```

Comment: Or change the type of `cacheFuture` to `CompletableFuture`, though it's better to code against interfaces as you proposed. Somehow most examples I see use the implementation instead of the interface.